# How to migrate java code to Jdev12c from eclipseIDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jdeveloper

I want to migrate running java application to Jdev12c. Can i use all the jar used in Eclipse as it is. I have eclipse related jars also i.e.

```
org.apache.commons.logging-1.0.4.v201101211617.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.0-RC2.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.5.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.oracle-2.5.0.jar
```

can i use these all jars in Jdev directly. and also apache logger file will work in Jdev or not. also do i need to change something in classes and code?

I have folders in the application and which have files. I am also using .property file. so can i directly use this all.

Answer (score 0):

JDeveloper has ability to import code from WAR file or a Maven project (import menu under file menu).
Or you can just create project from existing code.
You'll need to point to the jars in the project properties->libraries and class path

Comment: the project i am using can not be exported to WAR in eclipse. Well i have completed my work by copying all the content in new classes and files.